# Basic Countdown Timer

Tags: python, datetime, timer, gui, tkinter

Below is a class,`Countdown`, that takes seconds as input from an entry, and starts counting down when the `"Start"` button is pressed, while displaying the time left on a label:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime

class Countdown(tk.Frame):
    '''A Frame with label to show the time left, an entry to input the seconds to count
    down from, and a start button to start counting down.'''
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.show_widgets()
        self.seconds_left = 0
        self._timer_on = False

    def show_widgets(self):

        self.label.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.start.pack()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="00:00:00")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, justify='center')
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.start = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_button)

    def countdown(self):
        '''Update label based on the time left.'''
        self.label['text'] = self.convert_seconds_left_to_time()

        if self.seconds_left:
            self.seconds_left -= 1
            self._timer_on = self.after(1000, self.countdown)
        else:
            self._timer_on = False

    def start_button(self):
        '''Start counting down.'''
        self.seconds_left = int(self.entry.get())   # 1. to fetch the seconds
        self.stop_timer()                           # 2. to prevent having multiple
        self.countdown()                            #    timers at once

    def stop_timer(self):
        '''Stops after schedule from executing.'''
        if self._timer_on:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer_on)
            self._timer_on = False

    def convert_seconds_left_to_time(self):

        return datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.seconds_left)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)

    countdown = Countdown(root)
    countdown.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

**Review Concern(s):**

- My main concern is to code in an easy to read, efficient, and well-structured manner while still learning the language and concepts such as OOP. Feel free to mention the tiniest issue or improvement that comes to your mind, as I am a beginner and I probably need it.

---

Note: This was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105314/7032856) in SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very clean code indeed, there's not much to be said here.

**PEP8**

I'm sure you've been lectured on this before, but there's an official style guide for Python called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It states that module-level class definitions should be separated by two lines:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime


class Countdown(tk.Frame):
    ...
```

You also leave the first line of every method blank (or make it a docstring). If a function is undocumented, I wouldn't bother adding a blank line:

```
def foo():
    do_stuff()
```

If you decide to add a docstring, I'd recommend the following structure:

```
< function definition >
    < docstring (may span multiple lines) >
    < blank line >
    < function body >
```

For example:

```
def bar():
    """I'm a docstring!
    Blah, blah.
    """

    do_stuff()
```

**Private attributes**

It's good that you marked `_timer_on` as private. Why not do the same for `seconds_left` and the helper methods? This clearly tells other developers: 'I'm not part of the API. Don't rely on me for backwards compatibility.'. (Added bonus: you don't have to document private functions).

```
class Countdown(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def show_widgets(self):
        < docstring >

        ...

    def create_widgets(self):
        < docstring >

        ...

    def _countdown(self):
        ...

    def _start_button(self):
        ...

    def _stop_timer(self):
        ...

    def _convert_seconds_left_to_time(self):
        ...
```

Basically, any method, property, or attribute that isn't useful for end users, should be private.

**OOP**

`convert_seconds_left_to_time` could be a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod). A static method does not receive an implicit first argument. You should make a method static if it doesn't interact with the instance of the class, but is still strongly related to the class.

I'd then rename it to `_get_timedelta_from_seconds`:

```
class Countdown(tk.Frame):
    ...

    def countdown(self):
        """Update the label based on the time left."""

        self.label["text"] = self._get_timedelta_from_seconds(self.seconds_left)

    @staticmethod
    def _get_timedelta_from_seconds(seconds):
        return datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reviewing, I think you've made some good points. I agree with all the points here, will just try to make a habit of using these styles.